# Safari keeps losing cookies

Tags: safari, java, cookies

For like two weeks now I'm facing a strange issue with Safari (Version 15.5 (17613.2.7.1.8)) on macOS (Monterey), which keeps "forgetting" all cookies, including log-in ones.

That is extremely annoying because it happens really often - maybe every hour? And with most sites nowadays you have to enter 2FA as well so if you're logged in to multiple sites you're working with for the whole day, I bet I'd have to spend at least an hour every day re-logging to every single one. I've been using Safari almost exclusively for years now and have all credentials stored in Keychain so switching to a different browser is an almost impossible task (I know I can have a look into Keychain for passwords but I'd prefer not to look into it multiple times a day).

I'm not aware of any changes to my system, other than uninstalling Java JDK 16.0.2 (I think that was the version...). The reason for uninstalling that was another weird issue - for some reason, whenever I clicked a button on any page, it "clicked" the back button and I got redirected back - this no longer happens after uninstalling Java. I definitely didn't install any browser extensions.

Any thoughts what might be causing that and how to fix it?

Comment: Side note: Safari 15.5 can export passwords as a CSV file.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (for almost half a year) but haven't found any solution yet

Comment: FWIW, I'm still seeing this problem on macOS 14.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

Having the Safari developer tools enabled is [known](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/safari-keeps-logging-me-out-of-all-sites.2343060/?post=31215522#post-31215522) to [sometimes cause](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/446541) this, unfortunately.

Unchecking "Show Develop menu in menu bar" in the Advanced tab of Safari settings seems to fix it.

[image]

I switched to [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) a year or two ago to get around this issue, which has consistently worked, but a problematic preview release a couple weeks ago caused other problems and has renewed my quest for a better solution.

Given that it doesn't impact everyone with dev tools enabled, I wonder if there's some other contributing factor, like request overrides or something.

Comment: I just deleted all my (deactivated) request overrides. It will be a delightful surprise if it manages to resolve the issue.

Comment: It didn't. I now use Chrome when I need dev tools, and have them turned off in Safari. I stopped using Safari Technology Preview altogether.

Answer (score 1):

What is your cookie `sameSite` option? Is it `strict`?
I'm using Safari 15.2. When I quit Safari and reopen it. The cookie is gone because of the `strict` sameSite, it happened with the `back where you left` feature. But when you select the URL and press `Enter`, the cookie appeared.
My guess is Safari cannot load Cookie with `strict` when it try to reload the previous session.